# what does "ls'" mean in Linux?

Tags: linux

I accidentaly typed `ls'` and I got a interactive interface: `>`
What is this?

I tried search on internet, found nothing.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This behavior is distro agnostic.
You had open a quote, the shell is displaying `$PS2` global variable (`$PS2` is the `>` in your output) while the second quote is missing.

You can change PS2 with what you want instead :

Ex: `export PS2=">>>"`

The value of $PS2 is printed (after expansion) as the secondary prompt for more data when bash is running interactive. See `man bash`, under PROMPTING.

Comment: You have good eyes to spot the stray single quote.

Comment: Added info: To get out, just enter another single quote, or press ctrl-c.

Comment: Not exactly reading stdin; you can enter a multi-line quote in a script or something just as well; but the secondary prompt is displayed in an interactive session when you enter a newline inside a quoted string, an unfinished loop, etc.

Comment: Better use ctrl-d instead of ctrl-c as EOF (End Of File)

Comment: tripleee, right, post edited

Comment: @Anders Lind, see my edit

Answer (score 5):

```
-bash-4.1$ ls'
>
```

it means that you open a long string with `'` and didn't close it so bash is waiting for string(argument) ended with `'`

Use `ls` without any `'` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

"PS" stands for (probably) "prompt string".  PS1 is what the shell would display as your shell process's command line prompt.  PS2 is displayed when further input is required to complete the command (unquoted string, reading from stdin, etc.).  `man bash` then search for PS1 or PS2 (`/PS[12]<CR>`)